# Weblogic Server 12c recognize application (ear) as library

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c, ear

When i try to deploy the enterprise application (ear) to the Weblogic Server 12, WLS recognizes it as library and sets the radio button "Install this deployment as a library" (as in the picture below).
[image]
Every deploy I have to change radio button to "Install this deployment as an application". It doesn't cause any serious problem but it's easy to make a mistake during deploy process.

What is responsible in the ear for the proper recognition of the deployment type?

Below is ear content tree (I had to hide jars in libs, and change some application and packages names, but everything is consistent with the convention)

`.
├── APP-INF
│   └── lib
│       └── *.jar
├── testApp-ejb.jar
└── META-INF
    ├── application.xml
    ├── MANIFEST.MF
    └── maven
        └── pl.goralczyka.test
            └── test-ear
                ├── pom.properties
                └── pom.xml`

Comment: Post the ear content tree

Comment: @fantarama Thanks for answer. I've included ear content tree in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ran into the exact same problem and finally got the solution!

In my case the problem was the MANIFEST.MF content. I compared other projects Maven build to find the differences and the only thing was different that the maven-war-plugin had the `addDefaultImplementationEntries` enabled.

To further test the theory I tried the `addDefaultSpecificationEntries` option too and the result was the same.

So if your WAR has either `Implementation-*` OR `Specification-*`it will treat it '**as a library**'.

I know this is an old question, I hope this will help someone with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The extension is what is used to identify the type. The question has to do with the Weblogic console deployment procedure.

This question simply means that an EAR can be used as a library for other applications.